# Rails 7.0.5 Form being submited twice on click?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a Rails app and I see that every time I press the submit botton I get a duplicated request. I belive it has to do with TurboLinks, but I am trying to start an animation after the form contents are submited to the server, who will then send back some information needed for the animation.

This is what I have for JavaScript:

```
    const numberForm = document.getElementById('number-form');
    numberForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
     ---rest of the code that checks content--

    --- this is the part that sends the data to the server ---

     const formData = new FormData(numberForm);
            fetch(numberForm.action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                barsAnimation(numbersArray, data.data.result);
            } 
            else {
                console.error('Error submitting the form!');
            }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('An error occurred during form submission:', error);
            });
```

The server gets the data, sends it to another Python App I've got and then sends it back to the client

```
            if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
                data = JSON.parse(response.body)
                puts data
                render json: {success: true, data: data}
```

I can clearly see that I am getting the form contents twice, this is the content I have on the server side:

```
Started POST "/" for ::1 at 2023-06-27 14:02:34 +0200
Started POST "/" for ::1 at 2023-06-27 14:02:34 +0200
Processing by PushswapController#send_data as */*
Processing by PushswapController#send_data as */*
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "input"=>"3 2 1"}
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "input"=>"3 2 1"}
```

Additionally, once the animation starts on the client side (also using JavaScript) I see that the console.logs() I have are being logged twice.

I believe it has to do with TurboLinks which I am probably not using correctly, but I am not even sure where to begin to look for it,

I am trying to get the form contents to be submited just once per click

Comment: Have you tried event.stopPropagation as well?  If it is turbolinks related your submit event might be triggering that event handler too.

If that's still not fixing it, and it is due to the turbolinks submit handler on forms, you might have to specify the capture: true parameter on your event listener to ensure that it runs before the turbo one.